# Is it true that $\#\{J \cap \mathbb{Z}\} \geq b-a-1$ or $\#\{J \cap \mathbb{Z}\} \geq b-a-2$?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $A$ be a bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}$ and $J$ be a bounded interval in $\mathbb{R}$. Define $\lambda(A)=\#\{A \cap \mathbb{Z}\}$. Let $a=\inf J$ and $b=\sup J$. If $[x]$ denotes the integer part of the real number $x$ then:

i) $\lambda(J) \leq \lambda([a,[b]+1[)=[b]-a+1 \leq b-a+1$, if $a \in \mathbb{Z}$;

ii) $\lambda(J) \leq \lambda(][a],[b]+1[)=[b]-[a]\leq b-a+1$, if $a \notin \mathbb{Z}$.

**My question:** Is it true that $\lambda(J) \geq b-a-1$ or $\lambda(J) \geq b-a-2$?

This is being used to prove that $vol(I) \leq \sum_{j=1}^{n} vol(I_j)$ if $I, I_1, \dots, I_n$ are bounded intervals in $\mathbb{R}^{N}$ and $I \subset \bigcup_{j=1}^{n}I_j$, in some lecture notes on measure theory that I found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have that $J \supseteq [\lfloor a \rfloor + 1, \lfloor b \rfloor)$ whenever this makes sense (i.e. whenever $\lfloor a \rfloor + 1 \leq \lfloor b \rfloor$) by the definition of $a, \, b$ and the floor function. It follows that $$\lambda(J) \geq \lambda([\lfloor a \rfloor + 1, \lfloor b \rfloor)) = \lfloor b \rfloor - 1 - \lfloor a \rfloor = \lfloor b \rfloor - \lfloor a \rfloor - 1 \geq b - 1 - a - 1 = b - a - 2.$$ Finally, note that if $\lfloor a \rfloor + 1 > \lfloor b \rfloor,$ then $\lambda(J) \geq b - a - 2$ (since this quantity is negative in this case), so this inequality is **always** true.

Btw, if you know that your interval $J$ is closed, you have the improved inequality $\lambda(J) \geq b - a - 1.$ I hope this helps. :)

Comment: Could you explain how to prove that $J \supseteq [\lfloor a \rfloor + 1, \lfloor b \rfloor)$?

Comment: $J$ is an interval, so $(a, b) \subseteq J.$ At the same time, $\lfloor a \rfloor +1 > a$ and $\lfloor b \rfloor \leq b,$ hence the inclusion from above holds whenever it makes sense.

Comment: Thank you for the answer!

Comment: You're most welcome! :)